# Will the HttpContext.User property be set even if I do not use methods of the FormsAuthentication class?

Tags: asp.net

Who sets the `User` property of the `System.Web.HttpContext` object? I am assuming that the classes responsible for authentication, such as one of the methods of the `FormsAuthentication` class, would be setting this property after successful authentication.

What if I use forms authentication in my application but without using any of the methods of the `FormsAuthentication` class such as `RedirectFromLoginPage` but instead use `Response.Reirect` instead? Will the `User` property still be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpApplication` of your web application (inherited by your global.asax) exposes an event `AuthenticateRequest` which you can subscribe on from within an `IHttpModule`.

If you take a look at the `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule` then you'll see that it uses the `FormsAuthentication` class itself to read/write the authentication cookie.

That authentication cookie is added to the list of cookies that will be sent back in response to the web request. It doesn't matter whether the response is a redirect made be a call to `RedirectFromLoginPage` or a simple `Response.Redirect`, the cookie will be sent down and each subsequent request will send that same cookie to the server, where it will be processed by the `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule`, which in its turn will set the `User` if the authentication cookie is available and valid.

You can also subscribe to that same `AuthenticateRequest` inside your own `IHttpModule` or directly in your global.asax by specifying the following method for instance:

```cs
public class MyApplication : HttpApplication
{
    ...
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // assign here some custom `IPrincipal` to the Context.User property
    }
    ...
}
```

That way you can even set your own `IPrincipal` implementation if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I'd forgotten about the forms auth http module. One has to remind oneself of these things. I was just reading about it a few days ago when I read about the request life cycle within the bowels of the ASP.NET runtime.

Comment: No wait, my question now is -- what if I do not call the method that sets the forms auth cookie? How will ASP.NET know that my user has been authenticated if I never call that method that sets the forms auth cookie?

Comment: one way or the other, if the authentication cookie is not set, then the user is not authenticated and the `FormsAuthenticationModule` will see this and depending on your configuration will redirect the user to the login page.

Comment: just wondering, but if you do not want to write that authentication cookie, then why do you still use Forms authentication?

Comment: thank you. My question is born out of my private musings. It is based on a hypothesis. I am not not going to set the forms auth cookie. I was just wondering about the root cause of things, i.e. where things happen and why.